# Reading files from URL with ogr2ogr

Tags: ogr2ogr

I'm trying to move from downloading geodata manually and then working with it using ogr2ogr on the local file to just reading the data in from the url directly in order to have the actual source in the code and save myself some work.

For example I'd like to grab this [county boundary](https://data2018-mcgov-gis.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/moco-boundary) from the url: https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/4286963f248b46829ed860f4743eb85e_0.zip

[this command](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html) works for me:

```
# ogrinfo a shapefile in a zip file on the internet:

ogrinfo -ro -al -so /vsizip//vsicurl/https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OSGeo/gdal/master/autotest/ogr/data/poly.zip
```

but when i change it to point at the county boundary it is unable to open the source.

```
ogrinfo /vsizip//vsicurl/https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/4286963f248b46829ed860f4743eb85e_0.zip
```

Do I need to supply a layer name within the zip folder?

Comment: If you add `--debug on` to the request you will get a bunch of GDAL errors `VSICURL: HEAD did not provide file size. Retrying with GET
VSICURL: GetFileSize(https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/4286963f248b46829ed860f4743eb85e_0.zip)=0  response_code=200
VSICURL: Request at offset 0, after end of file
VSICURL: Request at offset 0, after end of file`. I can't say what they mean.